Error A 'contents' key is required al enviar archivo hacia un api con Http cliente LARAVEL
Estoy tratando de enviar un archivo de video desde mi app en laravel mediante POST usando hacia una API,y me genera un error A 'contents' key is required e intentado todas las soluciones posibles y no encuentro la solucion.
Este es la funcion de mi controlador que recibe los datos de mi formulario POST.
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'nameVideo' => 'required|max:255',
        'videoFile' => 'required|file|mimes:mp4,mov,avi|max:3072000',
        'datePublication' => 'required|date',
        'producer' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(',', $this->producers),
        'selectArtist' => ['required', 'array', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            foreach ($value as $artist) {
                if (!in_array($artist, $this->artists)) {
                    $fail("El valor $artist no es válido para el campo $attribute.");
                }
            }
        }],
        'selectCategories' => ['required', 'array', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            foreach ($value as $category) {
                if (!in_array($category, $this->categories)) {
                    $fail("El valor $category no es válido para el campo $attribute.");
                }
            }
        }],
        'newCategories' => 'nullable|string',
        'descriptionVideo' => 'nullable',
    ]);

//Las validaciones se hacen correctamente

    $video = $request->file('videoFile');

    $data = [
        'nombreVideo' => $validated['nameVideo'],
        'fechaPublicacion' => $validated['datePublication'],
        'productora' => $validated['producer'],
        'listadoArtistas' => $validated['selectArtist'], // Array de artistas seleccionados
        'listadoCategorias' => $validated['selectCategories'], // Array de categorías seleccionadas
        'descripcion' => $validated['descriptionVideo'],
    ];

    // Enviar la solicitud HTTP con los datos del formulario y el video
    $response = Http::timeout(900)->asMultipart()->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . Session::get('api_token'),
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ])
        ->attach('video', file_get_contents($video->getRealPath()), $video->getClientOriginalName())
        ->post($this->endpoint_url, $data);

    return $this->handlerResponse($response, 'Error al enviar el video');
}

La API tiene que recibir estos valores
    String nombreVideo,
    MultipartFile video,
    Date fechaPublicacion,
    String productora,
    // DatosListadoProductora productora,
    List<String> listadoArtistas,
    List<String> listadoCategorias,
    String descripcion,

Y siempre obtengo este error.


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El codigo que mostras no tiene nada qeu ver con el error que mostras.. es mas... el error te dice en donde esta el problema... que tiene que ver con tu codigo????

porque el error esta en el attach, no puede obtener el contents del archivo

normalmente cuando consumes un api, si esta esta bien diseñada es posible que tenga control de los parametros, por ese motivo si no incluyes en lo que enviar una llave contents, te va a mandar un mnesaje de error de retorno diciendo que te hace falta ... hay que ver en la documentacion del api... contects que es ... si un base64 o que tipo de dato espera ...

La solución fue esta.
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'nameVideo' => 'required|max:255',
            'videoFile' => 'required|file|mimes:mp4,mov,avi,mkv|max:3072000',
            'datePublication' => 'required|date',
            'producer' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(',', $this->producers),
            'selectArtist' => ['required', 'array', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                foreach ($value as $artist) {
                    if (!in_array($artist, $this->artists)) {
                        $fail("El valor $artist no es válido para el campo $attribute.");
                    }
                }
            }],
            'selectCategories' => ['required', 'array', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                foreach ($value as $category) {
                    if (!in_array($category, $this->categories)) {
                        $fail("El valor $category no es válido para el campo $attribute.");
                    }
                }
            }],
            'newCategories' => 'nullable|string',
            'descriptionVideo' => 'nullable',
        ]);
        $video = $request->file('videoFile');
        // Abrir el archivo en modo de lectura
        $handle = fopen($video->getPathname(), 'rb');

        // Crear los datos para el request multipart
        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'nombreVideo',
                'contents' => $validated['nameVideo'],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'fechaPublicacion',
                'contents' => $validated['datePublication'],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'productora',
                'contents' => $validated['producer'],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'descripcion',
                'contents' => $validated['descriptionVideo'] ?? '',
            ],
        ];

        // Añadir cada artista como un campo separado
        foreach ($validated['selectArtist'] as $artist) {
            $data[] = [
                'name' => 'listadoArtistas',
                'contents' => $artist,
            ];
        }

        // Añadir cada categoría como un campo separado
        foreach ($validated['selectCategories'] as $category) {
            $data[] = [
                'name' => 'listadoCategorias',
                'contents' => $category,
            ];
        }

        $response = Http::timeout(900)->attach('video',$handle,$video->getClientOriginalName())->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . Session::get('api_token'),
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ])->post($this->endpoint_url, $data);



        // Cerrar el handle del archivo
        fclose($handle);
        return $this->handlerResponse($response, 'Error al crear video');
    }

Agregar el contents y el name a cada parámetro. :)

No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.
